# [_UILabelLayer isHidden]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel and a checkbox button. When checkbox button is checked, display the uilabel,else display the label for 5 seconds and hide the label.When I go to other view and come back to this view,my app gets crashed saying "[_UILabelLayer isHidden]: message sent to deallocated instance "

```
   NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scanned!\n\nFormat: %@\n\nContents:\n%@", formatString, result.text];

if(checkbox==NO){

   [self hideLabel:display];

  }

 //method to hide the label for 5 seconds

- (void)hideLabel:(NSString*)text{

self.decodedLabel.hidden=NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];//3sec

 }


 -(void)hideLabel{

 self.decodedLabel.hidden= YES;   //app crashed at this point

 }
```

Could anyone tell me why this is crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

is causing issues. According to my understanding, you are popping the view controller and then coming back to it. when the controller is popped, all of the associated view are cleared and deallocated. Now in your case, this happens within the span of 5 sec. So when the timer hits, it cannot find that label(which is already deallocated).

So either you can use nstimer and invalidate it as soon as the screen goes away and hide/unhide the label when the next time screen appears depending upon the check mark state.

Please let me know if this helps.